# Query optimization in case of TIMESTAMPDIFF

Tags: mysql, optimization, delete

I have a table where I need to delete all rows older than 5 hours. Currently I'm doing:

```
delete from my_table 
where TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, from_unixtime(round(created_on/1000)), now()) > 5
```

The `created_on` column is a time stamp stored in milliseconds. I think adding an index on `created_on` column won't help since the query has a computed value (correct me if I'm wrong).

The delete statement works fine for smaller data sets, however for larger data sets (30-40k rows) it often gets stuck. Why does the delete statement get stuck for large data sets and how can I improve performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should move all the calculations to one side of the comparison:

```
WHERE created_on < (unix_timestamp(now()) - 5*60*60) * 1000
```

`5*60*60` equals 5 hours

Comment: And don't forget to add that index :)